# Passing data between activity

Tags: java, android, xml

I have to retrieve the total number of permits required by the application, and store this value for use in a second Activity, but without letting it open with the intent. I wrote this code. I will continue to use the Intent to pass data between the Activity. I wonder why she returned as 0. Maybe something wrong in the for loop? I just can not understand where is the error

```
    try {
        PackageInfo packageInfo = getActivity().getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(value2, PackageManager.GET_PERMISSIONS);

        String[] requestedPermissions = packageInfo.requestedPermissions;
        if ( requestedPermissions != null ) {
            for ( i = 0; i < requestedPermissions.length; i++) {
                permissions.append(requestedPermissions[i]+"\n");
                int total = i++;
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.putExtra("totalPermissions",total);

            }
        }
    }
    catch ( PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e ) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

In another PreferenceActivity

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if(extras!=null) {
        int tot = extras.getInt("totalPermissions");

permissionsPreference.setSummary(""+tot);
```

In the Summary of Prefence return 0. Why? Where is the error?

Comment: Where are you actually passing the Intent from the first Activity to the second Activity?

Comment: In your first block of code you create an Intent, but it doesn't look like you actually do anything with it. [`getIntent()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#getIntent()) returns _the Intent that started the Activity_, so if you don't pass your intent to `startActivity()`, you can't get it with `getIntent()`.

Comment: Show us where do you start PreferenceActivity

Comment: Yes, you are right. Excuse me. Doing as you said I solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try These Code After `For Loop`

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.putExtra("totalPermissions",total);
```

and then `Start` Your `Activity` like `startActivity(intent);`

Comment: But I do not have to start the Activity in what interests me to know only the number of permits.